# Google Apps Script ScriptDb permissions issue

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script

I am having an issue trying to query the ScriptDb of a resource file in Google Apps Script. I create a script file (file1), add it as a resource to another script file (file2). I call file1 from file2 to return a handle to its ScriptDb. This works fine. I then try to query the ScriptDb but have a permissions error returned.

Both files owned by same user and in same google environment

See code below:

file 1:

```
function getMyDb() {  
    return ScriptDb.getMyDb;  
}
```

file 2 (references file1):

```
function getDataFromFile1() {  
    var db = file1.getMyDb(); // This works  
    var result = db.query({..............}); // This results in a permissions error!  
}
```

I am at a loss to understand why I can access file1 and get back a handle on the ScriptDb, but then am not able to query it, due to an permissions issue.

I have tried to force file1 to require re-authorization, but have not yet been successful. I tried adding a new function and running it, so any suggestions there would be gratefully received.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: This should work fine. I cannot reproduce this problem. The authorization on file1 though has nothing to do with this. You should check the authorization on file2. How are you running it? From the script editor? Maybe your query is buggy, have you tried a simpler one? Can you share its code with us?

Comment: Hi Henrique,

Thanks for the reply. This should work fine I agree, which is why I'm a bit stumped.

I am trying to run the function from the script editor using debugger via another method (in file2) that calls getDataFromFile1()

I have tried a simpler query, but to no avail.

This is the actual query in my code file that fails:  
var result = db.query({ silo: "config", area: "settings", property : "custAdminName"});

This is the ScriptDb record:  
{
    "area": "settings",
    "value": "Alfred",
    "property": "custAdminName",
    "silo": "config"
}  

Thanks  
Chris

Comment: sorry, didn't realise all the formatting would disappear

Comment: var result = db.query({ silo: "config", area: "settings", property : "custAdminName"});

Comment: { "area": "settings", "value": "Alfred", "property": "custAdminName", "silo": "config" }

Comment: Yeah... nothing wrong there. Sorry, I'm out of ideas to help you. Can you reproduce that yourself on newer simpler scripts?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in file1/line2.  It says "return ScriptDb.getMyDb;" but it should say "return ScriptDb.getMyDb();"

If you leave out the ()s then when you call file1 as a library, file1.getMyDb() will return a function which you store in var db.  Then the line var result = db.query({..............}) results in an error because there is no method "query" in the function.

Is that what's causing your error?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the problem was, a misunderstanding on my part regarding authorisation. I was thinking of it in terms of file permissions, when in fact that problem was that my code was not authorised to run the DbScript service. As my code calls a different file and receives back a pointer to a ScriptDb database it is not using the ScriptDb service, so then when it calls the db.query() it invokes the ScriptDb service, for which it is not authorised.

To resolve this I just had to create a dummy function and make a ScriptDb.getMyDb() call, which triggered authorisation for the service. The code then worked fine.

Thanks for the input though.
Chris